# Can you identify the bird in this photo?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I spotted this bird in [Bangalore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangalore), atop a building on a September morning.

[image: Image #1]
[image: Image #2]

Comment: He is Shikra (Accipiter badius) in India worldwide he is goshawk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like *Butastur indicus*, the grey-faced buzzard. The spotted breast and the greyish chin fit well.

[A nice picture can for example be seen here](http://www.iucnredlist.org/details/22695726/0])